# Какое слово написать

Tags: орфография

Какое слово корректней написать и почему?: "Под потолком висит огромная стеклянная люстра, (отбрасывая) (отбрасывающая) кривые блики на пол."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, с причастием, потому что причастный оборот находится сразу за определяемым словом: "Под потолком висит огромная стеклянная люстра, отбрасывающая кривые блики на пол".

Деепричастный об. отстоит от сказуемого. Хотя и то и другое  возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно подчеркнуть, как она висит ("отбрасывая..."), можно изменить порядок слов так, чтобы просматривалось совместное "висит, отбрасывая". "Под потолком огромная, вся из стекляшек люстра висит, отбрасывая в пол свои изогнутые блики."